# Why ("abc"+char.MaxValue).CompareTo("abc")==0?

Tags: c#

I have a sorted array of strings.
Given a string that identifies a prefix, I perform two binary searches to find the first and last positions in the array that contain words that start with that prefix:

```
string [] words = {"aaa","abc","abcd","acd"};
string prefix = "abc";
int firstPosition = Array.BinarySearch<string>(words, prefix);
int lastPosition = Array.BinarySearch<string>(words, prefix + char.MaxValue);
if (firstPosition < 0)
    firstPosition = ~firstPosition;
if (lastPosition < 0)
    lastPosition = ~lastPosition;
```

Running this code I get firstPosition and lastPosition both equal to 1, while the right answer is to have lastPosition equal to 3 (i.e., pointing to the first non-matching word).
The BinarySearch method uses the CompareTo method to compare the objects and I have found that

```
("abc"+char.MaxValue).CompareTo("abc")==0
```

meaning that the two string are considered equal!
If I change the code with

```
int lastPosition = Array.BinarySearch<string>(words, prefix + "z");
```

I get the right answer.
Moreover I have found that

```
("abc"+char.MaxValue)==("abc")
```

correctly (with respect to my needs) returns false.

Could you please help me explaining the behavior of the CompareTo method?

I would like to have the CompareTo method to behave like the ==, so that the BinarySearch method returns 3 for lastPosition.

Comment: Whatever `BinarySearch` uses here (f.e. `string.IndexOf` or `CompareTo`). It ignores the hex value of `Char.MaxValue`. Search for `ignore` in [**Jon Skeets blog**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/strings.aspx) and you see that it's possible. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx): _"The CompareTo method was designed for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the Equals method."_

Comment: This piece of code is part of a more general purpose function that performs "range" searches on different data types, provided that the searched object implement IComparable. For this reason I though the binary search was a flexible solution, while using text-dedicated data structures such as a prefix tree was not fit to the purpose. I think that a possible solution which saves the flexibility issues is to encapsulate the string type into a type that implements the "right" comparison in its CompareTo method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the MSDN, [`string.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a.aspx) should not be used to check whether two strings are equal:

> The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the Equals method.

To get the behavior you wish, you could make use of the overload that accepts an `IComparer<T>`:

```
int lastPosition = Array.BinarySearch<string>(words, prefix + char.MaxValue, 
                                              StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

This will return `-4` for `lastPosition` as there is no string with that prefix in the array. I don't understand why you expect `3` in that case...

Comment: The problem is that it is not my code that calls the CompareTo method, it is the Array<T>.BinarySearch method.

Comment: `if (lastPosition < 0)
    lastPosition = ~lastPosition;`
converts -4 to 3.
The StringComparer.Ordinal is the right comparer.
Now I have to decide how to plug it into the real code without breaking the generic flexibility.

Comment: @Esuli: Ah, ok. You wanted to have the `3` after your operations.

Answer (score 6):

`string.CompareTo()` does a current-culture compare. Internally it uses `StringComparer.CurrentCulture`, whereas the string equals-operator does a culture-invariant compare.

For example, if the current-culture is "DE", you will get the same results with "ss" and "ß":

```
Console.WriteLine("ss".CompareTo("ß")); // => 0
Console.WriteLine("ss" == "ß"); // => false
```

What you want is a culture-invariant compare, which you will get by using `StringComparer.Ordinal`:

```
StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("ss", "ß"); // => -108
StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare("abc"+char.MaxValue, "abc"); // => 65535
```

Comment: Godd answer. As an addition: OP might want to use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(..., ...)` or `String.Compare(..., ..., StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to achieve a culture-invariant, case-insensitive compare.

Comment: @Abbondanza Exactly. And there is also `string.CompareOrdinal("abc\uFFFF", "abc")`. But since the asker calls the `BinarySearch` method, he should pass the `IComparer<string>` instance called `StringComparer.Ordinal`.